# Identifying the cause of WebGL crashes on IoS/Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webgl, cocos2d-js

I’ve been developing a game which uses WebGL for rendering, and while on PC I get no crashes, on Android/IoS devices I get random crashes during gameplay.

I don’t see any particular areas that would cause crashes, however it still does.

Considering the conditions and frequency that it occurs, I’m thinking it could be a memory leak or allocation failure, but I can’t find a way to analyze this for sure.

I’ve tried changing browsers, so on Chrome/Firefox/Safari it crashes, but on Opera or Armorfly it doesn’t. Additionally, according to the browser the symptoms are different.

I’m using textures (about DreawCall: 70~100, createTexture: 120~200) which draws over 500MB of VRAM, so I’m also thinking it could be that the GPU’s garbage collection isn’t doing its job in time.

The problem is that I can’t find any sort of values or logs anywhere to help me diagnose the problem.

I’ll list the symptoms more closely here:

On Android, while using Chrome, on the Android Debug Bridge’s logcat the error does not show up in the log.

On crash, no error codes or anything appear on the screen.

When I try to remotely debug it using Developer Tool on my PC, again no errors appear in the console.

Similarly, when using IoS and Safari, nothing in Instrument’s log.

So here are my questions:

1. In this situation, how am I meant to debug and find the problem?
2. Is there anybody that’s had these sorts of problems? If so, how did you solve it?
3. Is there any advice I can be given that I can pay more closer attention to when developing the program?

Thanks